# Installing Vundle for VIM

Tags: vim, vundle

I can't Install Vundle

I've followed the instructions on GitHub;

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

and that's all...
Here's the tree of cd .vim

```
├── bundle
│   └── Vundle.vim
│       ├── autoload
│       │   ├── vundle
│       │   │   ├── config.vim
│       │   │   ├── installer.vim
│       │   │   └── scripts.vim
│       │   └── vundle.vim
│       ├── changelog.md
│       ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│       ├── doc
│       │   └── vundle.txt
│       ├── LICENSE-MIT.txt
│       ├── README.md
│       └── test
│           ├── files
│           │   └── test.erl
│           ├── minirc.vim
│           └── vimrc
└── $MYVIMRC
```

7 directories, 13 files

and in .vimrc

```
set nocompatible               " be iMproved
filetype off
```

in order to edit .vimrc I used in vim:

```
:e $MYVIMRC
```

Can you help get Vundle installed?

Comment: You missed the rest of the installation. (i.e. the parts you put in your vimrc)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

like @FDinoff said, you missed the stuff that should go in you `.vimrc`.

here is how it could look like:

```
" vundle {{{1

" needed to run vundle (but i want this anyways)
set nocompatible

" vundle needs filtype plugins off
" i turn it on later
filetype plugin indent off
syntax off

" set the runtime path for vundle
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

" start vundle environment
call vundle#begin()

" list of plugins {{{2
" let Vundle manage Vundle (this is required)
"old: Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" to install a plugin add it here and run :PluginInstall.
" to update the plugins run :PluginInstall! or :PluginUpdate
" to delete a plugin remove it here and run :PluginClean
" 

" YOUR LIST OF PLUGINS GOES HERE LIKE THIS:
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'

" add plugins before this
call vundle#end()

" now (after vundle finished) it is save to turn filetype plugins on
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

you can check out my `.vimrc` if you want (https://github.com/linluk/my-dot-files/blob/master/vimrc).

as described in the comments you need to install plugins after adding them to your `.vimrc`

**steps to install a plugin**

1. add it to you `.vimrc` between `call vundle#begin()` and `call vundle#end()`
2. save the `.vimrc`
3. type `<ESC>:PluginInstall<CR>`

**to update the plugins**

1. type `<ESC>:PluginInstall!<CR>` or `<ESC>:PluginUpdate<CR>`

**to remove a plugin**

1. remove it from the `.vimrc`
2. save the `.vimrc`
3. type `<ESC>:PluginClean<CR>`

Comment: What is the line  " Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'  "  doing? What is it calling?

Comment: It seems like now it can be changed to "VundleVim/Vundle.vim" since the repository has moved.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the steps as @linluk described but when I open a file with `vim` i don't see a result of the new installed Plugins. 
Fore example I installed the "powerline" plugin which should return at the bottom of my vim screen a fancy looking status line, but when I open a new File is still looks as before.
The only plugin which worked for me is "YCM" (YouCompleteMe), but I can't explain why it works for YCM and not for powerline or other plugins like ultisnips.

Comment: Did you run `:PluginInstall` command from inside vim after you added the plugin to your .vimrc?

Comment: found out that I wanted to install a deprecated Plugin which didn't work properly.

Answer (score -1):

If you have trouble with a Vundle install follow these steps:

- Remove vim files(eg:.vim,.vimrc etc) and vundle
- copy and paste code in your terminal install vundle

  - if any problem arises during installation press ENTER

    ```
    sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ets-labs/python-vimrc/master/setup.sh)"
    ```